# Googletrans stops working, Json.decoder error from characters and emojis

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, translate

Before I start -

Code:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import random
translator = Translator()

languages = ['af', 'sq', 'am', 'ar', 'hy', 'az', 'eu', 'be', 'bn', 'bs', 'bg', 'ca', 'ceb', 'zh-CN', 'zh-TW', 'co',
             'hr', 'cs', 'da', 'nl', 'eo', 'et', 'fi', 'fr', 'fy', 'gl', 'ka', 'de', 'el', 'gu', 'ht', 'ha',
             'haw', 'hi', 'hmn', 'hu', 'is', 'ig', 'id', 'ga', 'it', 'ja', 'jw', 'kn', 'kk', 'km', 'ko', 'ku',
             'ky', 'lo', 'la', 'lv', 'lt', 'lb', 'mk', 'mg', 'ms', 'ml', 'mt', 'mi', 'mr', 'mn', 'my', 'ne', 'no', 'ny',
             'ps', 'fa', 'pl', 'pt', 'pa', 'ro', 'ru', 'sm', 'gd', 'sr', 'st', 'sn', 'sd', 'si', 'sk', 'sl', 'so', 'es',
             'su', 'sw', 'sv', 'tl', 'tg', 'ta', 'te', 'th', 'tr', 'uk', 'ur', 'uz', 'vi', 'cy', 'xh', 'yi', 'yo', 'zu']
text = '''
hello
'''

for i in random.sample(languages, 102)[:30]:
    text = translator.translate(text, dest=i).text

print(translator.translate(text, dest='en').text)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tudor/PycharmProjects/Auto Translator/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    text = translator.translate(text, dest=i).text
  File "C:\Users\tudor\PycharmProjects\Auto translator\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 172, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
  File "C:\Users\tudor\PycharmProjects\Auto translator\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 81, in _translate
    data = utils.format_json(r.text)
  File "C:\Users\tudor\PycharmProjects\Auto translator\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\utils.py", line 62, in format_json
    converted = legacy_format_json(original)
  File "C:\Users\tudor\PycharmProjects\Auto translator\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\utils.py", line 54, in legacy_format_json
    converted = json.loads(text)
  File "C:\Users\tudor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\tudor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\tudor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What I am trying to achieve is an auto translator which is supplied with an input, then it is translated randomly around 30 times.

The code works fine, there are no errors, and it works normally, but it crashes from time to time. From what I have worked out, if you add an emoji or some characters(sophisticated eastern characters) generated by the translator to the text needed to be translated, it crashes and it supplies an error, which is nearly identical(I will get to why I can't reproduce it) to the one above.

Most of the time, when the program crashes I can run it again normally, and it will work normally with the inconsistent errors, but sometimes the code won't translate anything at all and it will crash instantly and I can't rerun the program again, even if I run a simple code like:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

print(translator.translate('buna', dest='en').text)

>>>should produce `hello`
```

It reproduces the same error. If I run the program without the library, it works fine. If I delete the whole folder (I use pycharm if it is any help, it creates a venv folder which contains the environment I use for the project), and I run the program again, it works fine, until it crashes again.

What I want solved:

- How can I stop the program crashing
- How can I be able to include emojis

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This error means your IP has been temporarily banned by Google Translate API. Yeah, I know - it should've been wrapped in a custom exception of `googletrans` saying exactly that. The problem is nobody exactly knows what are the exact conditions for triggering this ban by Google (you can consult [this](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas), but as far as my experience goes  I get blocked when I'm not even close to these limits). Also Google seems to change these conditions on regular basis.